# Under vs Underneath

Tags: word-usage

I was asked this question recently-
Are you wearing anything underneath your shirt?. So, I am wondering if it's possible to use under instead of underneath in the above sentence?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible.

Comment: Underneath can be used as a preposition, adverb, adjective (usually, but not always, predicative) and noun. - Under can be used as a preposition, adverb, and adjective (usually, but not always, attributive and often as a prefix) and is probably obsolete as a noun and a verb.

Answer (score -2):

**Under** is used when something is directly under another object.

**Underneath** is often used to say that something is covered by another thing.

Therefore, referring to the question : *"Are you wearing anything **underneath** your shirt?"*, that person is probably referring to the thing you are wearing inside, instead of "**under**" which the person would refer to the thing you wear at the lower part of you shirt.

Comment: I suspect that most people would interpret _under your shirt_ and _underneath your shirt_ as meaning the same thing rather than differently as you state.